# undefined method render_cell for Rails 3 Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-cells

I created a mountable engine with `rails plugin new golgi --mountable`. The [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) gem was added as a dependency on the gemspec file: `s.add_dependency "cells"`. Bundling, and running the generator `rails g cell cart show` produced the following structure:

```
app / cells / golgi / cart /show.html erb
app / cells / golgi / cart_cell.rb
```

I then tried to call `render_cell :cart, :show` in views/layouts/golgi/application.html.erb but I get an undefined method error:
`undefined method 'render_cell' for #<#<Class:0x000001009ec590>:0x00000100931600>`

Note that I am running the 'dummy' app (/test/dummy) provided for testing engines. 
What do I need to make cells work with a mountable engine?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably forgotten to restart your rails server after installing the gem.